# Enabling dragging functionality for images within a scrollable div for Web Apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop, touch, vertical-scrolling

There are images with some text in a div that contains native scroll bar. I want to make those images `dragable` keep allowing native `scrolling` to be functional on that div. Sliding fast on images shouldn't fire drag events, like what iOS home screen does. I'm looking to do this in `iPad` and `iPhone` with iOS6.1 for now.

Any suggestion and `jQuery` plugin will be helpful!